# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport() on some phones Kinvey Android?

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, kinvey

The following error is obtained when running my app using the Kinvey client library:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport
                                                     at com.kinvey.android.Client$Builder.newCompatibleTransport(Client.java:555)
                                                     at com.kinvey.android.Client$Builder.<init>(Client.java:609)
                                                     at ch.ethz.nervousnet.trialapp04.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2337)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Line in MainActivity class it points to is the following:

```
Global.setmKinveyClient(new Client.Builder(this.getApplicationContext()).build());
// Client if a library class, not the one I have created
```

It works on most phones, but on some phones does not work, what could be the cause?

Here is a screen shot of all the libs I have in the project :

[image: List of libraries available in my project]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

LoveMeow,

1. What is the Android version on phones where it is not working? Is it the same version or happens randomly?
2. Since it is working for you on some phones, all the dependent libraries seem to be added properly. Are there any other warnings that are being thrown?

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support